# Mac OS X Mavericks Setup file Retrieve

Tags: macos, setup

Is there any possibility of getting the `OS X Mavericks` installation file after `OS X Mavericks` is installed? I need to use it on another macbook.

Or is there anyway to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If the app itself was lost, you can always re-download it from the App Store. For installing on a second computer, I'd make a flash drive version of the install. You can follow this guide for creating the flash drive install [from this guide](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-create-an-os-x-mavericks-usb-installation-drive-1450280026).